# Multilevel dropdown menu in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I want to create the mobile menu like this website have https://goodhealthbyyourself.megawecare.com/ in next js

I found one package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multilevel-sidebar

But when I use this package in next js it is showing error document is not defined inside the package build index file

I tried to solve it using use client and use effect but it doesn't work for me.

Please help